# How to do get my async database connection to close?

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise, mysql2

Hi I am trying to execute a node.js function that opens a database connection, executes a query and then closes.

Everything works fine up until the point where I need the connection to close. I am assuming something is wrong with my syntax but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
async function databaseConnection() {
    const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

    var connection = await mysql.createConnection({
            host:'*******' 
        ,   user:'*******' 
        ,   password:'*******' 
        ,   database:'*******' 
    });

    var q = 'SELECT ******* AS sha1 FROM ******* limit 10';

    await connection.execute(q, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err){
            console.log("An error ocurred performing the query." + err);
            return;
        }else{
            console.log("Query succesfully executed: ");
            rows.forEach( (row) => {
                console.log('sha1 from db row: ' + row.sha1);
            });
        }
    });
    await connection.end(); 
}

databaseConnection();
```

Comment: I don't know about your connection end issues but this line looks wrong: `await connection.execute(q, function(err, rows, fields)`. You're mixing `async/await` and [error-first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/). Use one or the other. You probably want to do something like: `const rows = await connection.execute(q)`.

Comment: Yep that has fixed my problem. My connection is closing properly now. Thank you. Put that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Your answer covers it just fine. Just self-accept it when you can so it goes out the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nik Kyriakides made a good point about mixing async/await with callbacks which solved my problem. I'll paste it here to answer the question:

> I don't know about your connection end issues but this line looks wrong: await connection.execute(q, function(err, rows, fields). You're mixing async/await and error-first callbacks. Use one or the other. You probably want to do something like: const rows = await connection.execute(q). – Nik Kyriakides 57 mins ago